# Why there does the program exit?

Tags: freepascal

well, the following program opens a file and reads the first two strings that exist in the first line into two variables. The problem is that  I’ve been trying to see what’s wrong with the following program, but I can’t see why it’s not working.
The compiler compiles it without any problem, but when I run it, it says exited with exitcode 2.
The problem is that the file exists.
What seems to be the problem?
Can anyone please help me?
The code is the following one.

```
Program num;

Var
  f: Text;
  b, g: String;
  c: String[1];

Procedure thenum (a:String);
Begin
  Assign(f,'textfileoffile.txt');
  Reset(f);
  a := 'A';
  while not eof(f) and (a <> ' ') do
  begin
    Read (f,a);
  End;
  Writeln(a);
End;

Procedure sth ( j:String);
begin
  Assign(f,'textfileoffile.txt');
  Reset(f);
  j:='A';
  while not seekEoln and eof(f) do
  begin
    read(f,j);
  end;
  Writeln(j);
End;

begin
  Assign(f,'textfileoffile.txt');
  repeat
    Reset(f);
  until eof(f);
  thenum(b);
  read(f, c);
  sth (g);
  if eof(f) then
    Close(f);
  Readln;
End.
```

Comment: What is the point of the `repeat Reset(f); until eof(f);` loop ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

i think that the problem is, that you open same file a lot of times

```
repeat
Reset(f);
until eof(f);
```

and you open this file in your procedures, i think you must use f as a parameter of your functions and don't open it again, or make it global

Comment: Does that look better? I tried opening the file for once in the main program, but it steel doesn't work.
    Program num;
Procedure thenum (a:String);
Begin
Assign(f,'textfileoffile.txt');
Reset(f);
a:='A';
while not eof(f) and (a<>' ') do
begin
Read (f,a);
End;
Writeln(a);
End;

Procedure sth ( j:String);
begin
Assign(f,'textfileoffile.txt');
Reset(f);
j:='A';
while not seekEoln and eof(f) do
begin
read(f,j);
end;
Writeln(j);
End;


begin
Assign(f,'textfileoffile.txt');
repeat
Reset(f);
until eof(f);
thenum (b);
read(f,c);
sth (g);
if eof(f)then
Close(f);
Readln;
End.

Comment: you don't change smth at all